# Read and find the line in the file size of 1 GB

Tags: java, php, perl, text-files

I need to read a text file larger than 1 GB to look for a particular line. This should be written in Perl, PHP or Java. This method should not load the server.

What are some methods to do it?

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html for infomation on reading files in Java.

Comment: is that a an exam question or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "the right tool for the right job" attitude and can be bothered to learn new tools, perl, awk, even sed are very good tools for exactly this kind of job. Otherwise, any full language will do, Java can do this job as well. But use the buffered classes, like BufferedReader, otherwise this will be painfully slow.

Example in perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open INFILE, "<infile" or die;
open OUTFILE, ">outfile" or die;
while(<INFILE>) {
  $_=~s/source-regex/replace-with/g;
  print OUTFILE;
}
```

I one-liner would work, but is a little more complex.

Comment: Complex? `perl -nwe 'print if /source-regex/' input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Whoops, I understood that there would be some kind of replacement. This one-liner will do fine. Thanks.

Comment: Replacement is not complex. Just change the `m//` to `s///` and print. Same potatoes.

Answer (score 2):

Not a lot here to go on, but create a `BufferedReader`, read one line at a time and check to see if it is the line you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = 'what to be searched';
open my $fh, '<', '/path/to/the/file' or die "unable to open file: $!";
while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ eq $line) {
        print "found $line at line $.\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a one-liner:

```
perl -nwe 'print if /source-regex/' input.txt > output.txt
```

As a script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print if /source-regex/;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl input.txt > output.txt`

There are ways to optimize this, but not much more can be done with the information you have given. The search will take some time, and could be slow depending on your regex.

If you have security concerns, an explicit file open is safer:

```
open my $input, '<', shift or die $!;
while (<$input>) { 
...
```